# Gulp - throw err cannot find module 'q'

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, jekyll

I was to trying to setup Jekyll with Gulp but when I run `gulp` it gives me the following error:

```
C:\Users\Admin\jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync-master>gulp
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'q'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync-master\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\portscanner-plus\lib\index.js:3:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

I tried going to `C:\Users\Admin\jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync-master\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\interpret\index.js` and made these changes:

`var q = require('q');`

to

`var q = require('Q');`

I ran `npm install -g` but still nothing. Anyone knows why I am getting this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at npm help section on install command (by typing `npm help install` in your terminal).

Here is what you are doing:

> - **npm install (in package directory, no arguments):**
>
>   Install the dependencies in the local node_modules folder.
>            In global mode (ie, with -g or --global appended to the command),
>            it installs the current package context (ie, the current working
>            directory) as a global package.
>            By default, npm install will install all modules listed as dependencies.
>            With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable
>            is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in
>            devDependencies.

Here is what you want to do:

> - **npm install [@/] [--save|--save-dev|--save-optional]:**
>
>   Do a @ install, where  is the "tag" config. (See
>            npm help 7 npm-config.)
>            In most cases, this will install the latest version
>            of the module published on npm.

By typing  `npm install -g` you are installing your current package context as a global package which has nothing to do with your current problem. The error `Cannot find module 'q'` means that q module is not installed.

To solve it type: `npm install q` which will install q module locally in your project directory.

Comment: Thanks! I ran `npm install q` but now I see cannot find module 'gaze', I install via `npm install gaze` I get another cannot find module.. mime-types/batch/escape-html/http-errors/accept and a lot more... How do I npm install all modules at once?

Comment: If there is a package.json file, you can simply do it by typing: npm install

Comment: Well there is, but if delete the node_modules and do npm install, I get "node-sass@0.9.6 install: `node build.js Exit status 1" error. Tell the author that this fails on your system: node build.js
You can get their info via: owner ls node-sass. I don't know whats wrong.

Comment: Please post the gulpfile, package.json and the whole error message.